# Linux PC is generating traffic not picked up by `iftop` etc

Tags: linux, connection, bandwidth, traffic, iftop

Our internet is getting shaped, so excess traffic is affecting us far more than normal. I've narrowed down the source of traffic to my own PC, which is a freshly installed Xubuntu 16.10 machine. My router measures around 128 KB/s incoming with the machine on, and effectively 0 with the machine off. This seems to be quite constant. If I disable the interface by `ifdown` or equivalently with the NetworkManager tool, traffic also drops to 0.

However, trying to work out what is actually causing this is very intruiging. Tools like `iftop` and `nethogs` only report a very small amount of traffic, 4-5 KB/s when my machine is idle. These tools seem to report programs I am aware of (browser, email, ssh) accurately. The router still reports 128 KB/s incoming here.

How can I find out what is causing this traffic, and why are `iftop` and `nethogs` not finding it?

Comment: are you sure you are pointing iftop to the right adapter? I've got a few boxes where the primary nic is eth1, so I must specify the interface when invoking the command.

Comment: You checked for IPv6 traffic (`iftop` new enough)? You checked all interface visible with `ip link` (packets may be redirected to other interfaces by the kernel, e.g. for tunneling)? Do you see anything if you run wireshark on the specific interface in question?